# Going from an object callback to a short form lambda expression

Tags: kotlin

I noticed that the two onFocusChangeListener callbacks accomplish the same thing:

```
editTextPassword.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
    if (!hasFocus) validatePassword()
}

editTextPassword.setOnFocusChangeListener(object : View.OnFocusChangeListener {
    override fun onFocusChange(p0: View?, p1: Boolean) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
})
```

The first one is shorter and what most Kotlin developers will probably always use. It isn't clear to me from the Kotlin documentation how you go from the longer one to the shorter one. Can someone please explain this?

Even though the docs don't explicitly state it, it appears to be saying that an object expression is the equivalent of a "function type" (a.k.a lambda expression). I just don't see how the two are related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Java [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) that allows you to shorthand implementation of single-method interface by using a lambda expression.

There's only one functional difference when explicitly using object expression, that is you can refer to it (using `this`) which is not possible inside lambda.

Comment: Does this mean that if the Java interface has multiple methods, you can't use the short-hand method?

Comment: @AndroidDev SAM conversions only work when calling Java methods that use Java interfaces that have only 1 method.

Comment: If you know that ‘SAM’ stands for ‘Single Abstract Method’, then it's clear why it won't work for interfaces with two or more abstract methods…  :-)